# We know that Homomorphic image of an Integral domain can have zero-divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra

We know that Homomorphic image of an Integral domain can have zero-divisor i.e., the homomorphic image of an integral domain may not be an integral domain.

For example-

Let $ \ R \ $ be a ring (**integral domain**) and consider the quotient ring $ \ R[x]/(p(x)) \ $  such that $ \ (p(x)) \ $ is not irreducible.

Then $ \ R[x]/(P(x)) \ $ is **not an integral domain**.

The inclusion map $ \ R \to R[x]/(P(x)) \ $  is a ring homomorphism  .

Thus homomorphic image of an integral domain may not be an integral domain.

My question is-

**Can the above homomorphism be a group homomorphism rather than a ring homomorphism**  ?

or,

**Can a group homomorphism map an integral doamin (which is an abelian group) to Non-integral domain domain**?

Help me with this because I need to know accurately as I am doing Ph.D. in the related topic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By definition a ring homomorphism $f: (R,+, \cdot) \rightarrow (S, +, \cdot)$ is also a homomorphism of (abelian) groups $f: (R,+) \rightarrow (S, +)$ (we just forget about the multiplicative structure).

Comment: So group homomorphic image of an integral domain can have zero divisors . Is it true?

Comment: @yourmath Yes. However this is a bit weird. Because an underlying group homomorphism only cares about the addition. Yet zero-divisors is a multiplication related concept. There is no link anymore. It's like asking whether a (non-continuous) image of a compact space can be non-compact? Yes, but... what does it really give you?